# how to do I/O sniffing

Tags: linux, io, block, trace

For sizing purposes I need to understand what requirements an application has to the I/O subsystem. I would love to do what I call I/O sniffing and obtain a list of events from the block layer like this:

```
initiator XYZ requests block 4711 from device 0815
initiator BLA writes block 1234 to device 9876
```

I have been told blktrace was what I am looking for but I cannot get this info from that tool.

Comment: Also see Systemtap here: http://serverfault.com/questions/327985/linux-io-monitoring-per-file

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a job for SystemTap, the SystemTap [beginners guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/index.html) by Red Hat has some disk and IO sample scripts to get you started as does [sourceware.org](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/).